# Vuex state Map value changes don't propagate

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a Vuex store that contains a Map

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
state:
{
   foo: new Map()
   ...
}
```

and a getter

```
getFooDataById: (state) => (id) =>
{
  return state.foo.get(id).data;
}
```

and last but not least a `computed` function in the component

```
computed: 
{
  getData()
  {
    return this.$store.getters.getFooDataById(this.id);
  }
}
```

This works great initially but any changes made by a mutation to the state map (specifically the map values objects) do not propagate to the component.
Did I make a mistake somewhere or is it not possible to use Maps as vuex state objects? Is there any way to propagate the changes manually?

---

**Edit to question pending review of duplicate flag**

While it's true that Vue still does not react to new items set into a Map,
I believe the referenced duplicate question is a somewhat different scenario.

This question involves Vuex, so it is possible to force reactivity by replacing the Map in state with a clone within the mutation.

```js
mutations: {
  'ADD_TO_MAP' (state, [key, value]) {
    state.foo = new Map(state.foo)
    state.foo.set(key, value);
  },
}
```

Example [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/rYwvBe)

I'm trying to think if there's any down side to this, but it seems ok.
In any case, answers should be permitted to explore the options.

Comment: Maps are not reactive in Vue. https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2410

Comment: I wonder if this is truly a duplicate? Since Vuex is in the mix, you can make your app react to store Map changes by cloning the current Map in the mutation: `state.foo = new Map(state.foo)`. See this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/rYwvBe).